# What is the story of Lord Krishna's Panchajanya conch?

Tags: krishna

Lord Krishna killed the demon Panchajanya and made a conch of his bone and gave a name Panchajanya. What is the full story of this incident?

Comment: Don't delete a question, just because it's a duplicate. Keep it as a reference for the future visitors. It will serve as an another useful link in Google search.